# Get headers in grails view

Tags: grails, servlets, groovy, http-headers, user-agent

I am trying to get the User Agent header in a grails partial, and if the User Agent is Chrome, display a notification to download a chrome extension.

This is some code of mine that fails to achieve this:

```
<% def useragent = request.getHeader("User Agent") %>
${useragent + 'asdf'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
<% def useragent = request.getHeader("User-Agent") %>
```

With a hyphen?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing your own you could also consider something like what [Kevin Gill did](http://www.wthr.us/2010/02/03/simple-grails-browser-detection/).